# convert text file in zip file in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to convert text file in zip file.
This is my code

```
zipFile.AddItem(@"D:\Inbox\GRN.txt"));
zipFile.Save(Common.GetFileName(@"D:\Inbox\GRN.zip"));
```

from this I am able to zip the file .
But its zipping full path .
I want under Grn Folder only GRN.txt should be available.

but currently is happening like this =  GRN- Inbox-GRN.txt

Please help on this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send second parameter `directoryPathInArchive` as `string.empty`. So try this

```
zipFile.AddItem(@"D:\Inbox\GRN.txt","");
```

Comment: Thanks i also found one solution zipFile.AddEntry("GRN.txt",System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Inbox\GRN.txt"));

Comment: Great!!! and this will help you as well when you want to add more that one file in single zip using `zip.AddSelectedFiles("*.txt", folderLocation, "")` as well